# Impossible to configure boot on Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, boot, boot-camp

I have a Macbook Pro with a bootcamp running both Mac OS X Snow Leopard and Windows 7.

From Mac OS, I did a restart under Windows 7 but since I had not been using Windows for a long time, I completely forgot the user password.

Since it's not possible to log in, it's also impossible for me to boot back to Mac OS X.

I already tried :

- to press alt/option key at startup : a padlock appears asking for a password (which I had never set) whereas it should propose the different boot options.
- to press C key at startup : it launches Grub with a Bash-like command line (whereas it's supposed to be starting from CD !)

What else can I do ? Isn't there any boot.ini-like file which I could edit to have the correct boot order ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Why are you running GRUB on a Macbook? Are you sure that isn't just the EFI bootloader?

Comment: I really don't know how pressing C at startup ends up launching Grub. I would like to find the explanation for that but I really don't see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove a ram chip.
Turn computer on holding apple+option+p+r
let it chime twice while holding those keys
This is a pram reset.
this will remove the firmware password.

Luke forgot that part.

You can then put ram back in.

Comment: Ok, this time, it worked. Thanks to you and @Luke !

To summarize :
- you remove a ram chip
- you do a PRAM Reset holding Cmd+Option+P+R with 2 successive startup.
- you press alt key at startup : you can choose the OS to boot to.
- you can then put back your RAM chip.

Answer (score 1):

The padlock means there is an EFI Password set. To disable it without CD ROM access, remove a memory module, turn on the Mac, then turn off the Mac and put your original memory configuration back. Once you do this, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> when booting will bring up the proper boot menu

Comment: I'm gonna try your solution right after work. Thanks for your answer Luke.

Comment: I tried your solution, it worked so I decided to run a new setup of bootcamp deleting the old partition and installing Windows 7. The problem still comes back : the padlock shows up when I press Alt key. And this time, removing a RAM doesn't solve the problem. :/

Comment: Then something else is causing it... Other thenosx and windows, what else is installed

Comment: Well, there is no other operating installed but OS X Snow Leopard and Windows 7. Isn't it possible to set this padlock password in any way ?

Comment: Using the efi password utility